# Firebase does not retrieve fields in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve from my collection "Courses" 2 field.
Course code and Course name. My issue when retrieving is that I only managed to retrieve the first field.

```
builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return ListView.separated(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                  Divider(height: 1),

              // ignore: dead_code
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                DocumentSnapshot doc = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                return ListTile(
                  contentPadding:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 10),
                  selectedTileColor: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                  title: Text.rich(
                    TextSpan(
                      text: doc["Course code"],
                      children: <TextSpan>[
                        TextSpan(text: ":"),
                        TextSpan(text: doc["Course name"]),
```

and it shows me this error:

```
Exception has occurred.
StateError (Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform)
```

this is my firebase [image]

I only can retrieve course code I don't know why.

Comment: Please check if the following [documentation helps you.](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/)

Comment: Can you please let us know if the above documentation helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have a problem with how Flutter and Firebase interacts with each other. I would like to suggest to check the [following thread](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/3826)and especially the [comment](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/3826#issuecomment-715591362) posted by jschnip which could solve your problem

> This is probably related to recent changes in DocumentSnapshot, your
> factory is looking for the data map, which used to be in doc, but nows
> its in `doc.data()` - except DocumentID
>
> So for your factory, one way to change it would be to adjust to:
>
> ```
> Userr( id: doc.id, email: docdata['email'], username:
> docdata['username'], url: docdata['url'], profileName:
> docdata['profileName'], bio: docdata['bio'], subject1:
> docdata['subject1'], subject2: docdata['subject2']
> ```

> and when you call
> it, you'll need to do something like:
>
> ```
> doc.data();
>       newUserrr = Userr.fromDocument(doc, _docdata);
> ```